# How to read preferences, get value of profile setting from Selenium Firefox webdriver via geckodriver?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I can set a preference with [`set_preference`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=set_preference#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile.set_preference), for example:

```
profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
```

However, I can't figure out how I can read the current value of a setting?

Answer (score 3):

They are in the `default_preferences` instance attribute:

```
print(profile.default_preferences)
```

Looking at the code, it's a dictionary.

Comment: It's not defined in the default selenium FF profile (webdriver_prefs.json), thus you don't see it before the initial setting. It's default value is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a preference/setting, that is not exposed in selenium (it loads it from a file "webdriver_prefs.json", which has the ones it actually needs/can control), then you can get it from the about:config page itself.

**DISCLAIMER** - this approach uses Firefox js objects that may change in future versions - and thus, stop working.

The idea is - open "about:config", search for the key, and get its value. If you do that manually, you'll see this is not the regular html pages you usually work with - it's an xml full of namespaces etc. Yet the data is stored in a js object `view`.

So the flow is - open the config page, and do all the work through JS:

```
from selenium import webdriver


def get_preference(name):
    """ Runs a JS that a) sets the value of the searched-for setting to the name argument,
        b) looks for the value of the first element in the "table" below.
        Thus the name better be exact, and you'd better be looking for the 1st match :) """

    global driver
    value = driver.execute_script("""
        document.getElementById("textbox").value = arguments[0];
        FilterPrefs();
        view.selection.currentIndex = 0;
        var value = view.getCellText(0, {id:"valueCol"});
        return value;
    """, name)
    return value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ff_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        ff_profile.set_preference("general.warnOnAboutConfig", False)  # there's a nasty warning opening about:config (another setting not present in the selenium preferences ;)

        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ff_profile)
        driver.get('about:config')
        print(get_preference('devtools.jsonview.enabled'))
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Look at my other answer (and the 1st sentence of this one) - the preferences Selenium deals with are a) limited set, and b) just a simple python dictionary. The axiom in python is not to have setters/getters - but just get value from the the object itself; and as you've seen in the code, `set_preference()` is quite simple - it just assign the value to the key, in the same `default_preferences` dictionary.

Comment: Thinking about it, I think the real trouble you're having is "why doesn't selenium have a `get_preference()` method _- that will return **every** possible setting in the browser, ever._". If so - I at least don't have a solid answer; I can only presume. I presume this is not a part of the webdriver protocol, so there's no standartized way for it to get it from every supported browser; and what to say if the user calls `set_preference()` with some obscure setting - how should it do it, when there's no protocol for that. That's my thinking, at least.

Comment: I prefer not to - I strive to provide in the answers information I can justify, or at least have sound reasoning to believe is correct/"is the way I would have done it, if it was me doing it". That's not the case here - that's an explaination I am happy with, but it is as good as the next one :) >"Also, where can I find out more about this" - in the webdriver protocol specs - https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/ - it's an interesting (though a bit harsh) read; especially when you realize not all browser drivers have implemented it to the letter, though its last version is 8 months old.